# How to get LVL License Check functions under Android P

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I migrated my app to Android P (Level 28) and tested it on an emulator running Android P. The license check results with an error "No connection to server". In Logcat I found the message "Clear text Traffic Not Permitted".
    I added a config file network-security-config.xml with:
 cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" and added android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" in the manifest under the tag "application". But I got the same result.
In LogCat I found, that http://android.clients.google.com was called, but this did not appear in my app or the License Library LVL. I suppose it was called by the Google Play Store app. What can I do to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I am seeing on the emulator, the problem is not with your app, but it is actually a problem with the com.android.vending application.  This application runs separately on the emulator (or real device), and it is this application that actually sends the license request to google's servers.  Since, the com.android.vending application is the one that is sending the plaintext, it must be updated to either not send in plain text, or to exempt the appropriate traffic from the plain text limitation.  I had been seeing the same issue.  However, the good news is that it is now corrected.  If you download the very latest Android Pie Emulator Image with Google Play Store support (not Google API support, that one may still have problems), then this issue should go away.

Comment: I tried already the P emulator with Google Play support. But I was not able to get it be usb debuggable.

Comment: I did not have any problems with it being usb debuggable.  It worked well with my application.  Maybe try the x86 image instead x86_64 or vice versa.

Comment: I did it with both  L28 emulators with Google Play support (x86 and X86-64). USB debugging was enabled. But always the same result in Adb 'unauthorized', in LogCat *unknown emulator'. The L27 emulator with Google Play Support works.

Comment: The only way to test my app was to define a Beta test and lod the beta-version from Google Play to the emulator. Now the app works correct.